# Shortest total path among set of Latitude/Longitudes

Tags: python, clojure, mapping, graph-theory

I have a set of 52 or so latitude/longitude pairs. I simply need to find the shortest path through all of them; it doesn't matter where staring point or ending point is.

I've implemented Dijkstra's algorithm by hand multiple times before and don't really have the time to do it again. I've found a couple things that come close, but most require raw graphs with pre-computed weights for each edge.

Do you know of any libraries or existing scripts/applications which will compute the shortest path in this manner?  The code/libraries would preferably use Python or Clojure but it really doesn't matter.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a closed path, it is the Traveling Salesman Problem, and a sub-optimal but quite effective way to resolve it is to use [Simulated Annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing)

Comment: TSP doesn't require a closed path. Without a closed path, the problem is the same, just the metric for the total path length is different. On a closed path, the best path is the one where the `sum of all edges` is minimal. If the path does not has to close, it's the `sum of all edges - the longest edge`

Comment: @THC4k I know that wasn't the question at all, but that comment just totally let me finish my code in the easiest simplest way. I already had TSP solved with the closed path. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In python, the best graph handling library I was able to put my hands on is [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/). It supports a broad range of different algos for [short path search](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.traversal.html#module-networkx.algorithms.traversal.astar).

Go for it. It's really complete and well designed.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the [Traveling Salesman Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveling_salesman_problem), and therefore there is no efficient way to solve it?

Comment: It's TSP without the stipulation of ending where you started, so you should in theory get a much shorter total distance.

Comment: Pish! TSP is O(n!) isn't it? He's only got 52 pairs = something like 8.07e+67 possibilities, no? :p

Comment: No efficient way to find the _optimal_ solution perhaps... but there are _fairly good_ solutions.